# Is it correct to say "the truck will be able to fit under the garage door"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I think [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P5B0LjVS05s) from India and the readers are native or near native speakers.

[image]

The truck has a piece on its roof and it can not go through the garage door.

**At 8:40**, the video says "**the truck will be able to fit under the garage door**".

However, I think "**fit under the door**" should look like this.

[image]

I don't think "**the truck will be able to fit under the garage door**" is correct. It should be "**the truck will be able to fit under the top bar of the garage door frame**" or "**the truck will be able to fit through the garage door**".

Is it correct to say "**the truck will be able to fit under the garage door**"?

Comment: It's syntactically valid, but idiomatically "unusual" to include ***be able to*** in the context of #1 ***X fits Y*** or #2 ***X will fit Y***. Where we normally only use the future reference in #2 if X hasn't ***yet*** been "fitted" to Y. But as with many similar contexts, saying you ***will do X*** carries the unavoidable implication that you will ***be able to*** do X, and it will often seem rather odd to explicitly point out the fact of having that "capacity / ability" if you've got it at time of speaking anyway (but just haven't used it yet).

Comment: I don't see a problem with their sentence.  The context makes it perfectly clear what they mean, and is much clearer and less wordy than any of the alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct. In this case, the garage door is the retracted cover of the entrance. Going or fitting under something only describes the relative positions of two things. The usual closed position of the door does not matter.

For example, if you lifted a car 100m in the air and walked underneath it, you can "*fit under the car.*"